# What is held pending trial?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://www.rferl.org/content/ukraine-complains-russia-savchenko-detention/25458269.html

> Savchenko has already been ordered **held pending trial** until at least August 30. Her case is similar to that of Ukrainian filmmaker Oleg Sentsov, who was arrested in Crimea in May and transferred to a Russian prison and will remain in pretrial detention through at least October 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that Savchenko will be detained (in prison) until it is decided whether or not she will stand trial.

Comment: Yup. Same thing as "will remain in pretrial detention" in the last line.

Comment: @StoneyB: I glossed over that part--derp.

Comment: Technically it means "will be held UNTIL trial" though occasionally such people are released without a formal trial taking place. Often it is a euphemism for someone being detained without any hope of a proper trial. (Depends on the context.)